# Location Services shown on menu bar even though all apps are disabled

Tags: macos, menu-bar, services, geolocation

I have encountered a weird problem with my Macbook Pro (mid 2017/macOS Sierra 10.12.6). It shows the Location Services icon on the menu bar, many times a day, even after unchecking all application from location services except 'Setting Time Zone' & 'Find My Mac' (under 'System Services'). I have also unchecked 'Show location icon in menu bar when System Services request your location', that means 'System Services' can use location services without showing on menu bar.

Why does location icon show up, is there any app which is using location without my knowledge? I take my privacy seriously. or is it some malware/adware.
Please see images:

[image: Menu bar]
[image: Unchecked all apps]
[image: System Services]

Comment: When you click on the icon on the menu bar, what's shown as using location?

Comment: after clicking on that icon, it opens up 'Security & Privacy' in 'System Preferences', since all apps are unchecked nothing is shown regarding which app was using location service.

Comment: Does it go directly to System Preferences or [show a list like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9bTy.png) first?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the screenshots above, the location icon is most likely showing up because you are allowing System Services to access your location. As long as every app in that list is unchecked, the only services that will use your location will be System Services.